# Если создавать на Azure WCF приложение через студию, это бесплатно?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

Поделитесь опытом, если создавать на Azure WCF приложение через студию, это бесплатно? Изучение всяческих бесконечных древовидных меню на Azure рано или поздно приводят к выбору площадки размещения, за 'совершенно смешные деньги' в месяц :)